# Customize Owl carousel dots

Tags: html, css, owl-carousel

I want to customize Owl Carousel dots. When not active, it is just a circle with a grey border and a white background. When I hover or when active, I want a yellow dot inside that circle. I tried doing that with some css but I am not getting anywhere.

My code

```
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
  <div class="item">
    <h4><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></h4>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <h4><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150"></h4>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="owl-dots">
  <button role="button" class="owl-dot active"><span></span></button>
  <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button>
  <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button>
  <button role="button" class="owl-dot"><span></span></button>
</div>
```

The css:

```
.owl-dots button.owl-dot.active span, 
.owl-dots button.owl-dot:hover span {
   background-color: yellow;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 16px;
   width: 16px;
}
.owl-dots button.owl-dot{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 19px;
   width: 19px;
   position: relative;
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

I asked too fast. Found the answer. Here is the code for anyone who might be wondering

```
.owl-dots {
    text-align: center;
}
.owl-dots button.owl-dot.active span, 
.owl-dots button.owl-dot:hover span {
  background-color: #FEAE00;
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 12px;
  width: 12px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1px;
  left:1px;
}
.owl-dots button.owl-dot{
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: white;
   border-radius: 50%;
   height: 16px;
   width: 16px;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Would love to this website when finished !